# SyntaxError: invalid property id in JavaScript and Twig in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm having a problem with some JS in Symfony2. I'm not sure that symfony is involved but if it were... ^^
I've a file named commande.js called from a twig resource that have some problems with my auto-completion function.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){

    var liste = [
        {% for patient in liste_patient %}
        "{{ patient.nom }} {{ patient.prenom }} - {{patient.dateNaissance|date("d/m/Y")}} - id: {{ patient.id }}",
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    $('.autocompletion').autocomplete({
        source: liste,
        minLength: 3,
    });
});
```

The error message is:
SyntaxError: invalid property id
and its on the line:
`{% for patient in liste_patient %}`

I've found different guys with the same error message but I could not undestand how to fix my problem.

Comment: Change double quotation marks to single quotation marks inside twig statements (i.e. 'd/m/Y')

Comment: Appears to be a basic concatenation problem. Notice that you  are trying to use double quotes within double quotes? You can't do that, it thinks you are ending your string. As Alberto says, to fix this use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it doesn't work.
In fact it doesn't affect anything and it stills saying the same error message.
I think the problem is more about the twig "for" that JS doesn't get but I surely not sure!

Comment: Is the code in a .html.twig file or in a .js file?

Comment: @ValentinBEAULE It is an error that needs to be fixed though, if you fixed your current error the concatenation error would come next. Where and how have you defined: `patient` and `liste_patient`? Does `patient` have an `id` property?

Comment: I'm using Symfony so it's directly send to the the twig page.
Also, this code was working when it was directly include in the twig page but did not like to be put in a new file.
And thank you for the concatenation problem, I've fixed it.
Also the code file is a ".js".

Comment: So I'm still blocked here. Any one could help me please? I'll send you my gratitude by mail! ^^

Comment: So you're having a separate .js file included in the twig template with <script src="commande.js"></script> ?
You can't use twig functions outside twig templates, they won't work in your js files...